# Framework Architecture: Specify NSBundle to load .plist file from during singleton init

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, architecture, ios-frameworks

**tl;dr**

How to create a Singleton (which is a part of a framework) able to read `.plist` from **specific place** (NOT from the framework's bundle) during its initialisation?

The solution is posted below and based on the accepted answer.

**setup description**

My iOS application utilises a proprietary `UsefulKit.framework` where all common code goes to.

The framework has a `ConfigurationManager` (Singleton), responsible for loading some settings (e.g. Base URL, API Keys, etc..) from a `.plist` during initialisation ([RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) and provides `+ (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key;` API to other components interested in reading an application-wide settings.

`ConfigurationManager` stores a name of default `.plist` it expects to load during initialisation (see Question #3 below) which is `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist`.

The manager loads the `.plist` from `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`, and it used to work fine **before** the manager has become a part of the `UsefulKit.framework`. When it was a part of main app, it had respective `.plist` in the same bundle and was able to locate it by name. See the code from `ConfigurationManager.m` below.

```
NSString * const kDefaultEnvironmentConfigurationFileName = @"EnvironmentConfiguration-Default";

@interface ConfigurationManager ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *environmentInfo;

@end

@implementation ConfigurationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static ConfigurationManager *sharedEnvironment;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!sharedEnvironment) {
            sharedEnvironment = [self new];
        }
    });
    return sharedEnvironment;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.environmentInfo = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [self loadEnvironment];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadEnvironment {
    [self.environmentInfo removeAllObjects];
    [self loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration];
}

- (void)loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration {
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSString *defaultPlistPath = [bundle pathForResource:kDefaultEnvironmentConfigurationFileName ofType:@"plist"];

    assert(defaultPlistPath != nil); // <=== code crashes here

    //
    // processing the plist file here...
    //
}

// ...
// some code omitted
// ...

@end
```

**problem**

Now, when it is a part `UsefulKit.framework` the approach doesn't work. It works if only I ship the `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` bundled together with the framework, which I don't want to do, because the configuration is different between applications that might utilise the framework. The application must have respective `.plist` and uses framework's `ConfigurationManager` to access the settings.

This code, also does not work for unit-test target within the framework's Xcode project. I put `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` file into test target bundle and wrote this unit test:

```
- (void)testConfigurationManagerInstantiation  {
    [ConfigurationManager sharedInstance];
}
```

... the code crashes at `-loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration` (see above).

Debugging aforementioned method I see this:

```
- (void)loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration {
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

    // Printing description of bundle:
    // NSBundle </Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyWorkspace-asazpgalibrpubbrimxpbrebqdww/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UsefulKit.framework> (loaded)

    NSString *defaultPlistPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:kDefaultEnvironmentConfigurationFileName ofType:@"plist"];

    // Printing description of defaultPlistPath:
    // <nil>
```

The bundle is definitely not the one where my `.plist` could be found at. So, I started to doubt that I am doing something wrong architecturally.

**questions**

1. As `ConfigurationManager` built with Singleton pattern I cannot inject the bundle via [Constructor Injection](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/). In fact I cannot think of any kind of dependancy injection that plays "nicely". Do I miss something? Maybe a `static` var where the client app assigns the path?
2. Could framework internally search for some other bundles?
3. The name of `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` is hardcoded into `ConfigurationManager`'s internals, which smells to me, b/c other developer must know it and do the setup, but, I saw this kind of thing for many 3rd party frameworks (GoogleAnalytics, UrbanAirhip, Fabric), where the framework expects to find `.plist` at particular place (often different between frameworks versions). Thus, the developer should read the docs and prepare the environment as a part of framework integration.

Any suggestions for changing the architecture are welcome.

**solution**

The following is highly based on suggestions posted by [@NSGod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277952/nsgod), appreciate that! I would call the approach as some sort of (static?) dependancy injection.

*ConfigurationManager.m*:

```
static NSBundle * defaultConfigurationBundle = nil;

@implementation ConfigurationManager

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [ConfigurationManager class]) {
        /// Defaults to main bundle
        [[ConfigurationManager class] setDefaultConfigurationBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
}

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static ConfigurationManager *sharedEnvironment;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!sharedEnvironment) {
            sharedEnvironment = [self new];
        }
    });
    return sharedEnvironment;
}

+ (void)setDefaultConfigurationBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    @synchronized(self) {
        defaultConfigurationBundle = bundle;
    }
}
// ...
@end
```

*ConfigurationManager.h*:

```
@interface ConfigurationManager : NSObject

// ...

/**
 @brief Specify default NSBundle, other than [NSBundle mainBundle] (which is used, otherwise) where .plist configuration file is expected to be found during initialization.
 @discussion For some purpose (e.g. unit-testing) there might be cases, where forcing other NSBundle usage is required. The value, assigned in this method might be [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]], to get the bundle for caller.
 @attention This method must be called before any other method in this class for assignment to take effect, because default bundle setup happens  during class instantiation.
 @param An NSBundle to read Default .plist from.
 */
+ (void)setDefaultConfigurationBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle;

// ...
@end
```

On the callsite:

```
@implementation ConfigurationManagerTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    /// Prepare test case with correct bundle
    [ConfigurationManager setDefaultConfigurationBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
}

- (void)testConfigurationManagerInstantiation  {
    // call sequence:
    // 1. +initialize
    // 2. +setDefaultConfigurationBundle
    // 3. +sharedInstance
    XCTAssertNoThrow([ConfigurationManager sharedInstance]);
}
// ...
@end
```

The approach allows streamline framework usage from application target (at `mainBundle` is where the `.plist` exists), so `+setDefaultConfigurationBundle` is only needed for unit-testing so far.

Comment: What is the name of your `.framework` where the `ConfigurationManager` class resides? Is it `UsefulKit.framework`? If so, have you added the `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` file to that `UsefulKit.framework` project, and added it to the Copy Resources build phase of the `UsefulKit.framework` target? In other words, are you sure that the `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` file exists at `UsefulKit.framework/Resources/EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist`?

Comment: The `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];` code in `ConfigurationManager` is going to return the `NSBundle` for the framework where the `ConfigurationManager` class is found (i.e. `UsefulKit.framework`?). I'm confused why you say "put EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist file into test target bundle and wrote this unit test...". It's the framework that needs that config file...

Comment: @NSGod `UsefulKit.framework` is a framework name. `ConfigurationManager` is a part of the framework. The point is, I don't want   `EnvironmentConfiguration-Default.plist` to be a part of the framework. It must be a part of client application. The manager has to be "fed" with the configuration and be used with convenient API. I don't know how to make this right.

Comment: @NSGod thank you for your questions, that made me think the question wasn't clear. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, come to think of it, if you want to have the framework communicate with the application, you only need change one line of code:

```
- (void)loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration {
    // NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

When the `ConfigurationManager` class was part of your main application, `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` returned the main application bundle (i.e. the same bundle that would have been returned by `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. When you moved the `ConfigurationManager` class to a framework (which can also be considered a bundle), `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` began returning the `NSBundle` for your framework rather than the main application bundle.

When you call `[NSBundle mainBundle]` from within your framework, it will return whatever app is making use of the framework.

Alternatively, you could use a class method to set a default value that will be used during initialization.

For example, in your `ConfigurationManager` class public interface:

```
@interface ConfigurationManager : NSObject

+ (void)setDefaultConfigurationPath:(NSString *)aPath;

@end
```

In `ConfigurationManager.m`:

```
static NSString *defaultConfigurationPath = nil;

@implementation ConfigurationManager

+ (void)setDefaultConfigurationPath:(NSString *)aPath {
     @synchronized(self) {
         defaultConfigurationPath = aPath; 
     }
}
// additional methods
- (void)loadDefaultEnvironmentConfiguration {
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary
                 dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:defaultConfigurationPath];


    //
    // processing the plist file here...
    //
}

@end
```

By declaring the `defaultConfigurationPath` static, you make sort of make it a "class" variable rather than an instance variable. So you use a class method to alter its value before an instance of your class has even been created. I believe the code should work as is with ARC, though I'm not positive (still used to manual reference counting myself).

Your main app should make sure that `[ConfigurationManager setDefaultConfigurationPath:]` is called with the proper path before anyone calls `[ConfigurationManager sharedInstance]`. The best place to do that would be in the `+initialize` method of your app delegate, which is one of the first methods to get called:

```
+ (void)initialize {
   NSString *path; // get path for plist
   [ConfigurationManager setDefaultConfigurationPath:path];
}
```

Comment: static var was one of possible solutions I thought of. It is good extension to the idea to have a public setter. I am also still looking for possibility for a framework class to access application bundle somehow. Thank you.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I have just posted the solution I went with which is highly based on your advise. Thank you!